# How to use relatedProperty in a .propdesc file

Tags: xml, windows, shell, winapi, properties

I'd like to create a custom Windows property that's essentially like System.ItemDate, except without displaying the time component.  Now according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/propdesc-schema-relatedproperty), you can supposedly map one property to another.  So I thought I'd try something like this in my .propdesc file:

```
<propertyDescription name="MyCustomDateProperty" formatID="{A38D2933-B395-45CF-A09C-FBE0374D0ACD}" propID="100">
  <searchInfo inInvertedIndex="true" isColumn="true" columnIndexType="OnDisk"/>
  <typeInfo type="DateTime" multipleValues="false" isViewable="true" isQueryable="true"/>
  <labelInfo label="MyCustomDateProperty" />
  <displayInfo displayType="DateTime">
    <dateTimeFormat formatTimeAs="HideTime"/>
  </displayInfo>
  <relatedPropertyInfo>
    <relatedProperty relationshipName="System.RelatedProperty.Text" propertyName="System.ItemDate"/>
  </relatedPropertyInfo>
</propertyDescription>
```

But this doesn't work (my custom date column remains blank), and I also don't know what to use for relationshipName.  I've tried things like System.RelatedProperty.Date or System.RelatedProperty.DateTime, but I don't think those are in the right ballpark.  Any ideas?

Actually, I'd like to broaden my question to how to map properties for any type -- not just DateTime.  I can't seem to get any properties to map up, even for just simple text properties.  For example, I just tried mapping a simple string property:

```
<propertyDescription name="MySimpleTextProperty" formatID="{D7E4C036-B31C-4441-ABA4-BDC74006BFAE}" propID="105">
  <searchInfo inInvertedIndex="true" isColumn="true" columnIndexType="OnDisk"/>
  <typeInfo type="String" multipleValues="false" isViewable="true" isQueryable="true" groupingRange="Alphanumeric"/>
  <labelInfo label="MySimpleTextProperty" />
  <displayInfo displayType="String"/>
  <relatedPropertyInfo>
    <relatedProperty relationshipName="System.RelatedProperty.Text" propertyName="System.ItemNameDisplay"/>
  </relatedPropertyInfo>
</propertyDescription>
```

But this does not show any text when displayed as a column.  Is it possible that I'm misinterpreting the usage of relatedProperty?  Perhaps it's only useful for [IPropertyDescriptionRelatedPropertyInfo::GetRelatedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertydescriptionrelatedpropertyinfo-getrelatedproperty).  Maybe File Explorer ignores it for display purposes.

Comment: The xml usage of relatedProperty seems correct, refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/propdesc-schema-relatedproperty). And the System.ItemDate is the primary date of interest for an item. In the case of photos, for example, this property maps to System.Photo.DateTaken. Can you check this date exits for the specific item?

Comment: Or does it work if you map it to the System.DateCreated?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I just tried a simple string property mapped to System.ItemNameDisplay, but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer received at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d7d3ac31-99f3-4c8b-9452-3945124eb077/how-to-use-relatedproperty-in-a-propdesc-file?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) (credit to Fei Xue):

> Currently, the only thing you can do with relatedProperty at this time
>   is to define your own relationName, map it to another property for
>   each custom property and access it programmatically:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertydescriptionrelatedpropertyinfo-getrelatedproperty
>
> And to display the property as you want, you need to implement the
>   property handler instead of using relatedProperty.